Jetty 12 lists the contents of WAR files instead of executing them
I am trying to switch from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12. I'm trying the most basic possible thing. I created a simple web app using Spring Initializr. I selected WAR deployment, made the WAR file, and copied it into my jetty-base/webapps directory as ROOT.war. In my start.d, I have :
ee9-deploy.ini  ee9-webapp.ini  http2.ini  http.ini  server.ini  ssl.ini 

https is working fine. The server works. I go to the root context and I get simply a listing that shows META-INF, WEB-INF, and then org/. In other words, just the contents of the ROOT.war file.
I'm really stumped. Is there something else I need to do to tell Jetty, this is a web application, please load it? I've been using Jetty for years and never had to fight so hard to get it to deploy an absolutely bare-bones web application.

In case anyone else runs into this frustrating problem...
--add-modules=ee9-annotations

otherwise it won't start your application.
